# How to use EditFrame to edit Multilist field with search

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, glass-mapper, experience-editor

I have a slight problem :/ I have an item in sitecore which contains a `multi list field with search` looking like this:

[image: Multilist field in Sitecore Backend]

The field and selected values are mapped via Glass Mapper for Sitecore like this:

```
public interface ILookItem
{
    ID ID { get; }
    string LookHeadline { get; set; }
    string LookInformation { get; set; }
    Image LookImage { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<IThumbnailImage> Children { get; }
    IEnumerable<ISkuItem> ProductIds { get; set; } 
    IEnumerable<LookProductModel> Products { get; set; } 
}
```

ProductIds is the corresponding multilist field.

In my cshtml file I have mapped the productIds into an editframe to enable editing from experience editor:

```
@using (Html.Glass().BeginEditFrame(look, "Edit look", x => x.ProductIds))
{
    <p>@look.LookHeadline</p>
    <img src="@look.LookImage.Src" alt="@look.LookImage.Alt"/>
}
```

Above should be alright and it also represented correctly in experience editor, except I cannot change the values of the multilist field.

[image: Multilist field in experience editor]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This looks like a bug within Sitecore, unrelated to GlassMapper. Have you raised this issue with Sitecore (telling them the exact Sitecore version you are running)?

Comment: I have the same issue- looks like there is a js error saying it can't find the $('scLanguage') field, which would make sense since the edit frame opens in an iFrame, any feedback from Sitecore on this?

Comment: Did you figure out how to solve this? I am having same issues.

Answer (score -2):

If anyone is having same problem.
Navigate to

```
\Website\sitecore\shell\Controls\BucketList
```

Open BucketList.js file

Comment the following line.

```
self.contentLanguage = $('scLanguage').value;
```

Add the following line.

```
self.contentLanguage = $('ContentEditorForm').lang;
```

This should fix the issue.

Comment: While this may theoretically provide an answer to the question, it's more important to include as much of the relevant details as possible here.  Otherwise, if the link goes dead, the answer becomes irrelevant.